# Oшибка с установкой pyaudio

Tags: python, install, pyaudio

Tакая ошибка.Что  делать?

```
C:\Users\User>pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc1
e156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\
hon37-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\U
\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-p0q3sz3z\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(to
ize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();ex
compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\User\AppData\Loca
emp\pip-record-4fvk85hx\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-manage
-compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nol
 /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\pytho
-32\include -Ic:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include
IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Progra
iles (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program File
x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fo
ld\temp.win32-3.7\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include\pyconfig.
15): fatal error C1083: ?? г¤ ?вбп RвЄалвм д c< ўЄ<оз?-Ё?: basetsd.h: No such
le or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC
IN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe -
c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Tem
pip-install-p0q3sz3z\\pyaudio\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__
e__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file_
'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4fvk85
install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with
ror code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p0q3sz3z\pyaudio\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто скачайте [отсюда](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) прекомпилированную версию.